# Looking for examples on using Google Cloud Channels to detect when objects change in a bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

We are looking for an example implementation of the channels available on google cloud storage buckets. The documentation is sparse, giving only the methods and their inputs. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#createChannel

From our understanding we need to provide an address to the code sample below, however there is no detail on what that address should be. Is it a RESTful endpoint? Is it an API? A gcloud function?
The other part is how are we supposed to test this without deploying to production?

```
let fileRef = admin.storage().bucket();
let channel = fileRef.createChannel("channel1", {address: "{endpoint}"}, {}, function (err, channel, apiResponse) {
        if (!err) {
    // Channel created successfully.
        }
    });
```

Our intention is to create a channel that will pass notifications to our server whenever a file is updated in the bucket.
At the moment the code below will give an error about the address, regardless of what we provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit that, with my 2 GCP certifications, I never heard about Channel on Google Cloud Storage. And after a [quick search](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/channels), I understood why: it's not recommended.

For this, [PubSub notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) is preferred. You can read PubSub pull subscription form VM, or, if your application expose HTTP port, the push subscription all you to receive message in real time.
You can also trigger function on this event.

So, forget the channel, use PubSub it's better and well integrated with many product and libraries are up-to-date with this.

Comment: We shall try that since it at least has a tutorial. Thanks.